# how to use a variable in a command used for open along with (-|) pipe output where the filename is interpreted as a command that pipes output to us

Tags: perl, pipe

How can I use a variable in a command used for open along with `(-|)` pipe output where the filename is interpreted as a command that pipes output to us.

```
$cmd = 'ps -elf';
open( my $fh, "-|",$cmd  ) || die( "$cmd failed: $! " );
```

Here I want `$cmd = 'ps $myOptions';`
where `$myOptions` will be set to the required options lets say for example
`$myOptions = "-elf"`

How can this be done?

Comment: Your code should work although you will need double quotes (`"`) around the value of `$cmd` and all vars will have to be defined in a sane order

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string concatenation for this as $cmd = "ps ".$myOptions;

Comment: no neither string concatenation nor double (") work in this scenario, i tried all this before posting my question :(

Answer (score 1):

Double quoting the pipe works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $cmd = 'ps';
my $opt = "-elf";
open( my $fh, "-|", "$cmd $opt"  ) || die( "$cmd failed: $! " );

while( <$fh>) { print "line $.: $_"; }
```

Also working: `"ps $opt"`, join( ' ', $cmd, $opt)`,` $cmd . ' ' . $opt`and probably many other ways. You just have to make sure that the 3rd argument to open is a string, with the proper content`ps -elf`. For this you have to make sure you interpolate the variables (ie no single quote), and you don't end up with a list instead of a string (ie concatenate or use variables between double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the command as a single string (e.g, if your options may actually consist of several arguments):

```
my $cmd = "ps $myOptions";
open my $fh, "$cmd |" or die "$cmd failed: $!";
```

If you want to specify it as two strings (e.g, if `$myOptions` should always be treated as a single argument):

```
open my $fh, "-|", "ps", $myOptions or die "ps $myOptions failed: $!";
```

Comment: no it just runs $myOptions as a command not the actual command ps along with options in $myOptions :(